# How to ignore assert(false) in release mode?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

My program built in release mode fails on assertions.

How can I setup eclipse to generate a binary which doesn't compute `assert()` calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is simple:

Right click on project, select `Properties`. Go under `C/C++ Build`, `Settings`. Select the Release configuration, then `GCC C++ Compiler`, `Preprocessor`. Under `Defined symbols (-D)` add `NDEBUG`. This worked for me.